# Undefined method authenticated? form main::Object

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm learning Sinatra now and I'm building a tiny blog. I've got a little problem with an `authenticated?` method. I've set up authentication, and now I want the rest of my app to be loaded only when the user is authenticated. So, in my `app.rb` I have the following:

```
helpers do
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def authenticated?
    redirect '/login' unless current_user
  end
end

if authenticated?
  # get '/' { ... }
  # get '/new' { ... }
  # post '/new' { ... }
  # the rest of an app (creating, updating and deleting posts go here)
end
```

When I run the app, it returns me the following error

```
undefined method authenticated? form main::Object
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html) you'd use your `authenticated?` method as follows:

```
get '/' do
  if authenticated?
    # something
  else
    # something else
  end
end
```